# MySQL slow group by date_format

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table from Daloradius:

```
{CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
  `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acctsessionid` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `groupname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `realm` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `nasipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nasportid` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nasporttype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctsessiontime` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctauthentic` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calledstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `callingstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `servicetype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framedprotocol` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framedipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctstartdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstopdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xascendsessionsvrkey` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
  KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
  KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
  KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
  KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
  KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
  KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1797353 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

}

with 1797353 rows.

This query delays 0.7s:

```
select count(distinct(right(radacct.username,17))) as Navegant,0,0
            from radacct,userinfo
            where userinfo.company='98' and userinfo.username=radacct.username
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  userinfo    ref username,company    company 203 const   4811    Using where
1   SIMPLE  radacct ref username    username    66  radius.userinfo.username    7   Using where; Using index
```

But when I add date_format(acctstarttime,'%H') then it takes more tan 4s to run the query:

```
select   date_format(acctstarttime,'%H') as AA,count(distinct(right(radacct.username,17))) as Navegant,0,0
            from radacct,userinfo
            where userinfo.company='98' and userinfo.username=radacct.username
            group by AA
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  userinfo    ref username,company    company 203 const   4811    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  radacct ref username    username    66  radius.userinfo.username    7   Using where
```

How can I make this query faster?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of issues with the performance with Group By.  I have ended up using sub selects instead in some cases.  This article was super helpful to me:

http://kccoder.com/mysql/join-group-by-performance/

Essentially it boils down to taking this:
date_format(acctstarttime,'%H') as AA

out of your select statement and putting into a sub select like this:

select count(distinct(right(radacct.username,17))) as Navegant,0,0
            from radacct,userinfo, **select date_format(acctstarttime,'%H') as AA from some_table**
where userinfo.company='98' and userinfo.username=radacct.username

I know my syntax isn't correct, but it should give you the general idea.

Hope this helps,
Brian

Comment: Please add essentials of the article you provided link for to your answer. Link can be broken at some day, and your answer would not be helpful anymore.

Comment: This is slower... takes 11seconds with separate query.             
[select AA,count(distinct(right(radacct.username,17))) as Navegant,0,0
            from radacct,userinfo, (select date_format(acctstarttime,'%H') as AA,radacct.radacctid as id from radacct,userinfo where userinfo.company='98' and userinfo.username=radacct.username  ) as tblrad
            where userinfo.company='98' and userinfo.username=radacct.username and tblrad.id=radacct.radacctid
            group by AA;]

Answer (score 0):

```
where userinfo.company='98'
```

begs for `INDEX(company)`

It is unclear why you need both tables, since the *same* username is in both of them.  It seems like this would suffice for the first query:

```
select count(distinct(right(username,17))) as Navegant,0,0
        from userinfo
        where company='98';
```

If that works, then this compound index would be even better because it is 'covering':  `INDEX(company, username)`

Your second query would benefit from either INDEX, the latter on being better because it can be "Using index" at least for the `userinfo`.